# SMS to multiple numbers (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, sms

Is it possible to copy multiple numbers from a table to the clipboard then paste the same to the SMS.app's To-field, like possible using commas after each number?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but check out UIPasteboard which allows you to manipulate the system clipboard. You might try adding multiple NSURL 'sms:...' "items" to the general pasteboard to see if the sms app interprets them appropriately. Please reply and let me know if it works.

Also check out MFMailComposeViewController. I don't think it will internally support SMS, but you could use it to email multiple SMS numbers using a general SMS gateway, or use a lookup table of cell phone providers by number allocation block to use individual providers' gateways. Advantage of using MFMailComposeViewController is that you don't need to quit your app.

There are some "free text message", "free MMS message" apps on the app store that seem to use the later approach.